# Created_at save with the wrong timezone

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel app and i'm trying to save the users checkins and checkouts to my database

i have a model `Checkins` and i record it like created_at and updated_at

on my localhost it save with the right time for my timezome ( Egypt ), i tried to changed `app.php` file to the following

```
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
| This is a bad thing really i think there is a problem within the server, the datetime
*/

'timezone'        => 'EET',
```

it's working just fine on my localhost and save with the current right time, for the production it's save with UTC timezone

Also when i write in the production terminal the command date `date`, i get the following

```
Tue Mar 31 12:46:38 EET 2015
```

and i checked mysql for the timezone and i found it's getting the time from the system time

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
SYSTEM
```

What's wrong here ?

## UPDATE:

I created a php page with `date('H:i:s');` and it's print the right time

Comment: If you command line into the mysql instance on the production box and manually do an UPDATE with created_at = NOW() what gets inserted?

Comment: i get the right time format when i update NOW(), but still when saving the data from my app i get the wrong timezone

Comment: OK so we know that the fault is not with MySQL it is with your app/Laravel. Have you also set the locale in your app.php?

Comment: Try setting the timezone in app.php to `Africa/Cairo`. Also are the PHP versions the same on the two boxes?

Comment: I'm using php 5.5 and changed it to Africa/Cairo and still getting the same issue

Comment: As a general rule, server-side frameworks like Laravel will get their time and time zone info from the server. If your development server and your production server are set for different time zones, you'll see time differences in dev and production. That's one reason most of us store all SQL timestamps in UTC, and let the server adjust results for the client's time zone.

Answer (score 24):

To set the timezone for your Laravel app, change the `'timezone'` in your `config/app.php`

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
| This is a bad thing really i think there is a problem within the server, the datetime
*/

'timezone'        => 'America/Los_Angeles',
```

You can find the timezone you need [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: I just use `'timezone' => date_default_timezone_get()` so I don't have to worry about timezone in two places.

Comment: @grimmdude didn't even know PHP had that function :) Great idea!

Comment: @grimmdude I recommend setting it as UTC, that way you don't have to worry about time in different timezones..

Answer (score 5):

You have to change yout time zone in `config/app.php`

Also as is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46462169/9342837) you must run following commands for your time zone changes to be saved:

`php artisan cache:clear 
 php artisan view:clear 
 php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use `insert` or `insertGetId` to insert the data?

If you use `Eloquent(like ->save())` to insert data, the time will be right.

Answer (score -1):

As per [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) It is strongly recommended that you use the correct time zone for your location, such as `Asia/Shanghai` or `Australia/Perth` Not use `EET` or `CET`.

Your can find timezone for your location [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score -4):

Looks like you forgot to run php artisan config:cache.