# Laravel changing timezone not reflecting the correct time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am changing the timezone into `Asia/Singapore` at `config/app.php`, but when I try to do a `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` the result is still in UTC.

Is there anything in Laravel that overrides that timezone that I set at `config/app.php` ?

Comment: Do this `'timezone' => 'Asia/Singapore'` in `config/app.php` file and do `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @HirenGohel it didn't work.

Comment: run `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Is `php artisan config:cache` command works for you??

Comment: @HirenGohel yes, how do i mark you as the correct answer?

Comment: You already done! Thanks man! :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just do this:

`'timezone' => 'Asia/Singapore'`

in `config/app.php` file and run this 3 command:

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan view:clear` and

`php artisan config:cache`

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: When i run last command php artisan config:cache, my helper functions are not working

Comment: I had the same problem.

Comment: @ZionAdams: Last command not required if first 2 commands run and if the issue was fixed. Last command is not required. Let me know if first 2 commands run.

Comment: We have a system that's already been in production for months, we're having problem with datetime parsing and we're looking in to setting this to the proper time zone. Does doing so have any repercussions?

Answer (score 5):

Add this in `config/app.php` file:

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Singapore'
```

After, run this command:

```
 php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

At least in the generated application skeleton of Laravel 5.8, maybe other versions too, the timezone setting in `config/app.php` is
`'timezone' => 'UTC'`,
so it will ignore an `APP_TIMEZONE` in the `.env` file.

So put an e.g. `APP_TIMEZONE='Europe/Berlin'` in `.env` and modify the line in `config/app.php` to this:

```
'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC')
```

Or, when it's sure local, staging and production all run in the same timezone - change only the line in `config/app.php` to:

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Berlin',
```