# Laravel discrepancy between two date fields that should both be UTC

Tags: laravel, datetime, timestamp, timezone, utc

I'm on a project that uses Laravel 8.

My timezone is configured as such in my config/app.php file:

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

My migration is setup like this:

```
$table->dateTimeTz('sent_at')->nullable();
$table->timestampsTz();
```

And when I create a new record for this table I do something like this:

```
    $model = Model::create([
        'sent_at' => now(),
    ]);
```

Yet when I inspect the database, or when I display the dates in Laravel Nova for example, it seems like the `created_at` is stored/displayed in UTC but not the `sent_at`. They should be identical?

I end up with:

```
created_at: 2022-07-02 07:29:59
sent_at: 2022-07-02 10:29:59
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd like both these fields to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current time and date of timezone **UTC** using bellow lines:

```
    $date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
     echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Please check same question on stackoverflow [Laravel changing timezone not reflecting the correct time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423806/laravel-changing-timezone-not-reflecting-the-correct-time)