# Fetched Data in laravel automatically changes the timestamps value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, timestamp, laravel-10

So the problem is that I have a laravel vue project both are different applications, and I have done changes in the config/app.php in the `'timezone'='Aisa/Kolkata'` so the app shows local time of my country. Everything is fine like when adding new data to DB the timestamp is correct and updating the data also the timestamp is correct. But when fetching the data the time format changes to UTC
for example :- `2023-12-15 15:36:11` this is created_at field and its in correct format and time when it was created is also correct but when fetching it from laravel time changes its format to this `2023-12-15T10:06:11.000000Z`.

Below here is the example of my code with screenshots:-

[this is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6LYt.png)

here the created_at field has timestamp of `2023-12-15 15:36:11` and the code for fetching the time and data is

```
$res = AcCleaning::whereBetween('ac_cleaning_detail.created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
      ->join('peon_masters as pm', 'pm.peon_id', '=', 'ac_cleaning_detail.peon_ref_id')
      ->join('ac_masters as am', 'am.ac_id', '=', 'ac_cleaning_detail.ac_ref_id')
      ->latest('ac_cleaning_detail.created_at')
      ->select('ac_cleaning_detail.created_at')
      ->get();

      if (sizeof($res) > 0) {
           return $this->successResponseWithData("Fetched Successfully", $res);
      } 
      else {
           return $this->errorResponseWithoutDataWithErrorCode("No Data!!", Config::get('constants.HTTP_STATUS_CODES.NO_CONTENT'));
      }
```

this code gives me the timestamp when the AC is cleaned by using the created_at timestamp but upon checking the data in postman

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Fetched Successfully",
    "data": [
        {
            "created_at": "2023-12-15T10:06:11.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

the format and time changed to another timezone automatically

below here is the model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AcCleaning extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'ac_clean_id';
    protected $table = 'ac_cleaning_detail';
    public $fillable = ['peon_ref_id','ac_ref_id','longitude','latitude'];
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

I checked a bunch of solution and many of them are suggesting to create another method in model that changes the timestamp to carbon instance but how to call it when fetching a bulk of data.

Additionally why it is changing the time automatically. Am I missing something Please help.

I just want that timestamp should be fetched as it is stored. I am using laravel 10, php 8.2

Comment: did you try adding `protected $casts = ['created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s'];` inside the AcCleaning model  ?

Comment: @xenooooo Yes, Using that just changes the format , the value is still different as compared to database

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423806/laravel-changing-timezone-not-reflecting-the-correct-time
Basically, you might have done the correct update to config, but laravel might have cached the old value and is not looking at the new version of the config file.

Comment: @Techno i used those commands when updated the app/config.php file, also run it now, but it does not change the output. its coming in that format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, By defining the mutator in model I overcame the issue of datetime automatically changing to another timezone.

just  write the below code to your model

```
 protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date): string
{
    return Carbon::parse($date);
}
```

it will automatically changes to the specified timezone that you have given in the config/app.php