# How to change timezone using date() and strtotime() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, timezone

I'm still new in Laravel. I have a problem in understanding the concept of Carbon and the format for date and time. Everytime I create new post, the `created_at` column does not show the exact time as in my location. For example, currently in Kuala Lumpur the time is 2:36 PM but in my phpMyAdmin, it shows 6:36 AM. How can I change the timezone? And I'm using this code `<span> {{date('d/m/Y  g:i A', strtotime($comment->created_at))}} </span>`

Here is what I already tried.

**in my view blade.php**

```
<span> {{ date('d/m/Y  g:i A', strtotime($comment->created_at))->setTimezone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur')}} </span>
```

but it gives an error `Call to a member function setTimezone() on string`

**comments table**

```
created_at - datetime
```

Hope anyone can teach and show me the correct one. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Created\_at save with the wrong timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366835/created-at-save-with-the-wrong-timezone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your **app time zone** by configuring **`app.php`** file in **`config`** folder .

To change time zone , modify the value of **timezone** in app.php file.

This is written in this section

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
```

For me i am using **Asia/Kuala_Lumpur** as my application time zone.

Here is the appropriate syntax :

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
```

list of [timezones](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp) for PHP

> **NOTE** : run `php artisan config:clear` to effect this changes

Comment: remove old data and insert new data and run `php artisan config:clear` to effect this changes

Comment: Ya I need to do that command. Now it works. Thank you so much!